# Interplanetary space mission debris orbits

Tags: orbital-mechanics, debris, interplanetary, orbital-elements

I was wondering if anyone knew about a database of orbits for debris from previous interplanetary space missions. I am referring to debris or expired missions by NASA, ESA, JAXA, etc. I know there are obviously databases for Earth satellites, but I couldn't find any equivalent for interplanetary manmade debris.

For example, is there any info about where boosters from the Apollo program went?

Comment: There will likely be a Wikipedia page with a list of these, and I think there have been "deep space junk" questions here in the past that address aspects of this also. Certainly each Apollo mission's Wikipedia page will have some information about trajectories, but you're asking for a nice *database*. The situation is complicated because some items haven't been tracked and lost and are thought to have passed again later but the identification is uncertain.

Comment: Don't forget to include red Roadsters!    BTW,  boosters and the like all fell back onto Earth.  I don't think they count as "interplanetary"  material.

Comment: Atlas upper stages didn't all fall back to Earth @CarlWitthoft.

Comment: @GdD  Interesting -- what's their generally predicted orbital lifetime?

Comment: If only there was a database @CarlWitthoft!

Comment: Yeah, one of the apollo boosters was respotted and classified as asteroid J002E3 when it was temporarily captured by the Earth. They realized what is was bc the spectral signature matched the white paint used on the atlas boosters.